# wide characters transliteration C with towctrans

Tags: c, utf-8

I would like to convert (transliterate) UTF-8 characters to be closest match in ASCII in C. Characters like `ú` is transliterated to `u`. I can do that with `iconv`, with `iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT`, on the command line.

In C, there is a function `towctrans` to do that, but I only found documentation about two possible transliterations: to lower case and to upper case (see `man wctrans`). On the documentation, wctrans depends on LC_CTYPE. But what other function (other than "tolower" and "toupper") are available for a specific LC_CTYPE value?

A simple example with towctrans and the basic toupper transliteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t frase[] = L"Amélia"; int i;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (i=0; i < wcslen(frase); i++) {
        printf("%lc --> %lc\n", frase[i], towctrans(frase[i], wctrans("toupper")));
    }
}
```

I know I can do this conversion with libiconv, but I was trying to find out possible already defined `wctrans` functions.

Answer (score 1):

While the standard allows for implementation-defined or locale-defined transformations via `wctrans`, I'm not aware of any existing implementations that offer such a feature, and it's certainly not widespread. The `iconv` approach of `//TRANSLIT` is also non-standard and in fact conflicts with the standard: POSIX requires a charset name containing a slash character to be interpreted as a pathname to a charmap file, so use of slash for specifying translit-mode is non-conforming.